# How to move the Last Modified file in a folder to another folder

Tags: batch-file

How can I move the last modified file to another location?
Source List:

```
F:\MY DOCUMENTS\Vishnu srma CV_045485_20130228.doc  3/22/2013 2:40 PM
F:\MY DOCUMENTS\Vishnu srma CV_024867_20130228.doc  3/23/2013 1:40 PM
F:\MY DOCUMENTS\Vishnu srma CV_023556_20130228.doc  3/23/2013 3:50 PM
```

Target Folder:

```
F:\MY DOCUMENTS\zyx
```

Comment: This question might be voted down, Please describe properly

Comment: Your question makes it looks like you've got three files with the same name - that seems unlikely to me...

Comment: All files are in the same folder with the same file name: this can't be in Windows.

Comment: ya u are right endoro, sorry i missed to put the extantion numer which is auto genrated by the applicaton and it can be variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this should work:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /od "F:\MY DOCUMENTS\*.doc"') do set "source=%%~i"
copy "F:\MY DOCUMENTS\%source%" "F:\MY DOCUMENTS\zyx"
```

Comment: I also want's to rename those mooved files, suppose there are some files in F:\MY DOCUMENTS\zyx
I want's to rename those 

Balance Sheet_20130306_120249.xls  as BalanceMTD.xls
FS_20130306_114923.xls             as FS.xls
IC Activites_20130306_114923.xls   as ICActivitesMTD.xls
OS_20130306_114923.xls             as OS.xls

Comment: Please mark this question as answered and ask a new question.

Comment: it's wrokgin on my local machine..but when I am applying it on citrix it's not working properly...it's copying all files from folder..pl suggest

Comment: Please mark this question as already answered and ask a new question.